# ITC.apps.validation.screenshot itunes connect iPhone 6 screenshot is required

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-6

I have uploaded my app build to itunes connect from Xcode 5.1.1... I currently do not support iPhone 6. When I submit to review I get an error that I have to upload iPhone 6 sreenshots first.

```
ITC.apps.validation.screenshot_5.5-Inch_missing
ITC.apps.validation.screenshot_4.7-Inch_missing
```

Is there anyway I could just bypass iPhone 6 screenshots where as my app doesn't support iPhone 6 yet ?

Comment: have you tried using the iphone 6 / 6 plus simulator in xcode 6 gm? i did my screenshots with the simulator and the scaling was not perfect, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My App was accepted with Photoshop Scaled 4-inch Screens. However, for now apple stopped requiring iPhone 6 screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit an app that does not support iPhone 6. So I guess it makes sense that iTunes Connect now makes it compulsory to include at least one screenshot for the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus resolutions.

But unless you include launch images for the iPhone 6/6 Plus resolutions your app will run in scaled mode on the new iPhones. So as a quick workaround, I imagine that simply scaling your existing screenshots would give similar results to re-capturing them.

Comment: I wonder what Apple's policy will be, and if they'll reject apps that are quick-fixed like that. It's not as if this hadn't been long coming, with the advances in auto layout since iOS 6 and size classes in the recent betas.

Comment: Agreed, and I also wonder if they might reject apps that don't have native iPhone 6 resolutions enabled. Unless an app update is submitted to make a quick fix for a bug, it would seem important to support the iPhone 6 from now on when submitting an app.

Comment: "You can't submit an app that does not support iPhone 6" as of today this is totally wrong.

Comment: @mspasov I meant any app on the iOS App Store is expected to run on iPhone 6, even if not "optimised" for iPhone 6 (i.e. not running at device resolution). So iPhone 6 users have to see the app listed, and hence it makes sense that iTC forces you to upload iPhone 6 screenshots.

Comment: @Clafou There is a bug in iTC that incorrectly recognizes app as "Optimized" for iPhone 6/6+ and requires screenshots. I have two apps, that I update simultaneously. Both are not optimized for iPhone 6 and iTC requires screenshots for one of them..