# "You must provide a screenshot for 5.5-inch Retina display, because your app binary supports 5.5-inch Retina displays" while building in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've updated an old app with a minor bug fix. The app was compiled using Xcode 5.1.
(No way to use assets catalog or to add iPhone 6 and 6 Plus images.)
But still when I try to submit it to review I'm getting this error:

> You must provide a screenshot for 4.7-inch Retina display, because
> your app binary supports 4.7-inch Retina displays.
>
> You must provide a
> screenshot for 5.5-inch Retina display, because your app binary
> supports 5.5-inch Retina displays.

The easiest fix would be to upload 4.7 & 5.5 pics which is fine but I'm more worried about the "**because your app binary supports 4.7-inch Retina displays**" part.

Although it feels like a bug in iTunes connect, any one found a workaround for this?

Comment: I have almost identical issue, I'm submitting an app, that is build with Xcode 6.1, does not support iPhone 6 and 6+, and iTC wants 4.7 and 5.5 inch screenshots.

Comment: Here there is the answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831404/itc-apps-validation-screenshot-itunes-connect-iphone-6-screenshot-is-required the only problem is wether the reviewers will still accept re-scaled images at all. But the solution to that problem is solved by submitting the app to Apple.

Comment: Please check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440106/you-must-provide-a-screenshot-for-5-5-inch-retina-display-for-4-7-inch

Comment: "...while building in Xcode 5.1..." There's no asset catalog there.

Comment: Apple used to recognise whether you support iPhone 6 screen size, by checking whether you have a startup screen defined for iPhone 6 sizes. They may have changed the rules, but if you have iPhone 6 startup screens defined, then you should remove them.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

We've had the same issue yesterday although our app did not state support or optimization for iPhone 6(or +).
Using Xcode 6.1 to build the IPA, we've simply re-scaled relevant images, and had no further issues submitting the app.

**Update**
Some developers are not encountering the issue with their app's submission, while having no 4.7/5.5 inch scaled screenshots, meaning there's a possible flag in the binary which enforces this limitation.

**The longer version**

Apple now demands screenshots for the new screen sizes, without being dependent on the actual app binary.

As per the [Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html), if an app **states** it supports iPhone 6, it must provide at least one properly* scaled image ( * *proper size is listed in the link above*).

All current releases to the app store should support the latest device, including iPhone 6 and the 6+, by default, therefore the error message is terrible. There is no actual relation to the binary. Just a new iTunes Connect limitation.

This is a recently added limitation by apple as our previous release to the App Store using Xcode 6.0 did not require us to add these new scaled images.

Comment: This is not true, because I submit two applications - one is accepted without issues (no support for iPhone 6/6+, no screenshots for them), the other one requires. There is something in the binary that makes iTC believe that the app is iPhone 6 optimized..

Comment: @Roni , I don't think you're right. iTunes connect says "because your app binary **supports** 5.5-inch Retina displays". It's not and was compiled with Xcode 5.1

Comment: @mspasov are you submitting two apps who share the same core and differ by light modifications?

Comment: @Roni yes. One project with two targets.

Comment: @mspasov,@Segev,
editing my comment until we'll know more.
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Same problem here - seems indeed like a new requirement, my code was only changed marginally and accepted without 4.7/5.5 images just 3 weeks ago, and now it isn't anymore.

Comment: Same here submitting with Xcode 5.1, is there a solution beside using Xcode 6?

Comment: Same here, tried two different builds (only changed the build version) one uploaded with the application loader 2.9.xx and another uploaded with the application loader 3.x and in both the apple asked for the screenshots to the 5.5 and 4.7 inch iphones.

Two weeks ago i had uploaded an IPA of the same application and apple did not ask for that screenshots

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and I discovered that it was because I had inadvertently set the "Launch Screen File" (General Project Settings) to the name of Main.storyboard. When I cleared that out I was able to Submit for Review successfully.